# How to correctly import custom widgets in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a widget(W2), made of other widgets (W1). Each has a corresponding .kv file as below. Running main.py, I expect to see a black background with two labels, vertically stacked. Instead, I get both labels on top of each other, so something has gone wrong.

```
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <W1>
```

So I thought, "Maybe I should import w1.py in w2.py even though it's not explicitly used in the py file? That ... sort of worked. I get both labels on top of each other, as in the following image.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to write a widget that is expected to be imported/included by another widget? And the correct way to import it?

I tried using `Builder.load_file()` in the .py file and just importing the .py file but that had similar results.

**w1.py:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
kivy.require('1.10.0')

class W1(Widget):
    text = StringProperty('default')

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(W1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**w1.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<W1>:
    text:
    Label:
        text: root.text
```

**w2.py:**

```
import kivy from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
# from w1 import W1  # added this to get a working, but the incorrect layout
kivy.require('1.10.0')

class W2(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(W2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**w2.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:include w1.kv

<W2>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    W1:
        text: 'w1.1' 
    W1:
        text: 'w1.2'
```

**main.py:**

```
import kivy
from w2 import W2
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require('1.10.0')


class mainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

**main.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:include w2.kv

W2:
```

**EDIT**
The overlapping has been resolved, though maybe not correctly. I had W1 inherit from BoxLayout rather than Widget, with the thought  that maybe there was a minimum height/width property missing in the base Widget class.

I'm still not certain what the "correct" way to handle importing a widget which has a paired .kv file is, or exactly why I'm getting overlapping widgets when I inherit from Widget; only speculation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

why are you using two different kv files for this?
I would say the proper way would be similar to what i have with my kv file. because you are spliting up things that can be done on a single page and if you need different pages you use the `ScreenManager` import stuff

**main.py**:

```
`
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widgets import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayut import GridLayout

class MyGrid(Widget):
     pass


class MyApp(App):
     def build(self):

 # this calls what we want to show in the kv file
         return MyGrid()



if __name__ == "__main__":
MyApp().run()
`
```

## file is written like this because the App falls off and in order to link the 2 it must have the same name

**my.kv**:
#  "<>" Basically links `MyGrid` from the .py file and then displays the
#   gridlayout and such

GridLayout:
rows: 2

```
        Label:
           text: "whatever"
        
        Label:
           text: "whatever 2"
```

Comment: Yes, my specific example could be done in a single page. It is a minimum viable example, but suppose I have one widget that I expect to be in many different widgets in my project. The point is that I was (I no longer even use kivy...) trying to do something that *could not* (or should not) be done in a single page.